# Is it normal that LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is missing from an environment?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, ld

I have found by coincidence that on my Debian Jessie there is no `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable (to be exact `printenv | grep LD` shows nothing related to linker and `echo "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` shows also nothing).

This is the case in x terminal emulator ([which might clear it due to setgid](https://superuser.com/a/49724/61694)) as well as in basic terminal (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F1</kbd>).

I know that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` [may be considered bad](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html) so Debian may block it somehow, but on the other hand there are a few files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` that contains some directories to be added to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. None of my rc files (that I know of) mess with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` either.

Why I don't see an `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it is normal that you don't have any explicit `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Read also [ldconfig(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html) and [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) and about the [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath). Notice that `ldconfig` updates `/etc/ld.so.cache`, not the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Sometimes you'll set the *rpath* of an executable explicitly with `-Wl,-rpath,`*directory* passed to `gcc` at link time.

If you need a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (but you probably should not), set it yourself (e.g. in   `~/.bashrc`).

If you need system wide settings, you could e.g. consider adding  `/usr/local/lib/` in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run `ldconfig` after installation of every library there.

AFAIK `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used only by the dynamic linker `ld-linux.so` (and by [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) which uses it) after [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). See also [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html).

Read Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) for more.

Comment: That was my mistake, I though that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the _product_ of running `ldconfig`. Meanwhile it is the _input_ of ldconfig alongside with files in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

Comment: My feeling is that `ldconfig` don't use `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (which is only used at `ld-linux.so` time)

Comment: @calavera.info it's neither. The dynamic linker uses `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` *together* with the output of `ldconfig` at runtime. `ldconfig` neither uses nor changes `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Now I can see that I had it totally messed up, probably by spending too much time in Java, where "classpath" is virtualy the only configuration of dynamic linking. Everything seems to be clear now, thanks a lot.